# Nested multisig - how to sign tx with child multisig?

Tags: multisignature, gnosis-safe, gnosis

I'm trying to create a nested multisig safe.

Parent Safe: 2/2

- owner 1: EOA
- owner 2: child multisig

I've set up a child safe and a parent safe and added the child safe address as owner to the parent safe.

Now creating a tx in the parent safe requires the child safe to confirm the tx.

How do I confirm / interact with the parent from the child safe?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [WalletConnect Safe App](https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/4356253-walletconnect-safe-app) via the owner Safe to confirm transactions.

If you open the WalletConnect Safe App in the parent Safe, you can then connect the child Safe via WalletConnect to the parent Safe.

Comment: I think I understand what you're getting at, but can you expand on how exactly to do that?

Comment: By opening the WalletConnect Safe App in the owner Safe, you will be presented with a field to enter the WalletConnect connection URI. Keep this open.

Open the child Safe in a new tab/window and try to connect to it via WC. You'll be presented with a QR code modal, below which is a "Copy to clipboard" link. Clicking that saves the WC connection URI to your clipboard. You can paste this in the URI field in the WC Safe App open in the owner Safe.

You can then use the owner Safe as you would any other EOA. Transaction requests will pop up in the tab/window which the owner Safe is open in.